# The xterm launches OK on freshly rebooted machine only

Tags: xquartz

The xterm launches OK on freshly rebooted machine only. After awhile, it won't launch any more. The behaviour is the same if I try to launch it from a terminal window or from the XQuartz Application menu. The other X pgms work OK, like xman, xeyes, etc.

If I start the xterm from command line the 'ps' shows that there are two xterm instances and if I kill either, they both disappear.

If I start xterm from the XQuartz Application menu nothing happens, but 'ps' shows that there is one xterm instance. If I kill the xterm instance I get blank xterm window which does not respond to anything and 'ps' does not show any xterms any more.

I'm running macOS 12.0.1 iMac Pro and XQuartz 2.8.1

However, on my MacBook running 11.6.1 and XQuartz 2.8.1 I haven’t seen this problem.

It seems that the problem is triggered at least after starting Android Studio. (Actually, the problem is triggered by some internal process as xterm won't launch after awhile even if there were no user activity.)
The only way to make the problem go away (temporarily) is to reboot the machine.

Output if XQuartz started from command line:

```
% /opt/X11/bin/startx -- /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz
font_cache: Scanning user font directories to generate X11 font caches
/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental:
font_cache: Updating FC cache
font_cache: Done
xauth:  file /Users/…/.serverauth.1858 does not exist

xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1
```

Defaults:

```
% defaults read -app XQuartz
{
    "NSWindow Frame SUStatusFrame" = "1080 960 400 135 0 0 2560 1415 ";
    "NSWindow Frame SUUpdateAlert" = "970 762 620 398 0 0 2560 1415 ";
    SUHasLaunchedBefore = 1;
    SULastCheckTime = "2021-11-06 07:25:16 +0000";
    SUUpdateGroupIdentifier = 3364357597;
    SUUpdateRelaunchingMarker = 0;
    "app_to_run" = "/opt/X11/bin/xterm";
    "apps_menu" =     (
                (
            Terminal,
            xterm,
            n
        ),
                (
            xman,
            xman,
            ""
        ),
                (
            xlogo,
            xlogo,
            ""
        )
    );
    "cache_fonts" = 1;
    "done_xinit_check" = 1;
    "enable_iglx" = 0;
    "login_shell" = "/bin/zsh";
    "no_auth" = 0;
    "nolisten_tcp" = 1;
    "startx_script" = "/opt/X11/bin/startx -- /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz";
}
```

Pkg info:

```
% pkgutil --file-info /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app
volume: /
path: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app

pkgid: org.xquartz.X11
pkg-version: 2.8.1
install-time: 1635673703
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 40755
```

Display environment variable:

```
% echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.R6t1d1sET9/org.xquartz:0
```

Process list:

```
% pgrep -fl Xquartz
712 /opt/X11/libexec/launchd_startx /opt/X11/bin/startx -- /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz
713 /bin/sh /opt/X11/bin/startx -- /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz
871 xinit /opt/X11/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz :0 -nolisten tcp -iglx -auth /Users/XXX/.serverauth.713
877 /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz :0 -nolisten tcp -iglx -auth /Users/XXX/.serverauth.713
```

Comment: What is the command line you use to launch xterm from xterm?

Comment: Normally 'xterm &' but '/opt/X11/bin/xterm &' gives the same result. But I start xterm from iTerm, not from xterm.